# use dictionary to filter values on a colum in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I find many question for mt topic but noithing really works,
I have the follow columns

| Zoekterm | Mogelijke Bias |
| --- | --- |
| met ballen | 0 |
| jonge man | 1 |
| vrouwen | 1 |
| kind | 2 |
| jonge man | 1 |

I want to find a specific value in my dictionary and make a new column:

```
dictionary = {"Zoekterm":['met ballen']}
data['Zoekterm'].map(dictionary).fillna(data['Zoekterm'])
print(data[data.Zoekterm.isin(dictionary.values())])
```

I thought to start very simple, but it's not working

The result that i want is this:

| Zoekterm | Mogelijke Bias | Zoekterm_nieuw(New column) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| met ballen | 0 | met ballen |
| vrouw | 1 | met ballen |

Can someone help me?

Comment: @Umar.H thanks for replay i created with your code a new colum 'Zoekterm_nieuw'  but i gives me a empty list with no value that exsist in my dictionary

Comment: can you show a few more entries in your dictionary?

Comment: Try this:  `df['Zoekterm_nieuw'] = df['Zoekterm'].map(dictionary).fillna(df['Zoekterm'])`

Comment: @Umar.H i eddit my question and add more values thansk for helping

Comment: i think you need `.loc` `df.loc[df['Zoekterm'].isin(dictionary.values()),'Zoekterm_nieuw(New column)'] = df['Zoekterm']`

Comment: @Ank it give me still the list with all the values but i want to get back only the values that are in the dictonary

Comment: @Umar.H i still get an list with NAN values when i use .dropna() i get empty list

Comment: @Umar.H i have meeting is 10 min, can i send you  my file by email? i write my code in jupyter

Comment: @Umar.H i wanted to send you a message by twitter but i cant send you a message do you have time after 4:30 pm just 15 min i appricate this

Comment: @Umar.H Hi do you have link where i can join the meeting? i dont see any link yet